# I want to split the text in the row into separate columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, string-splitting

I have this column and rows
[image]

I want to split the text in the row into separate columns like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case where every string to split has a non-numeric prefix and ends with a contiguous series of numeric digits you want to return separately, something like the following may suffice:

```
DECLARE @T table ([Terminal Kodu] varchar(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT @T ([Terminal Kodu]) VALUES ('e-manat1135592398');

SELECT
    [Name] = LEFT(T.[Terminal Kodu], FirstNumeric.position - 1),
    Code = STUFF(T.[Terminal Kodu], 1, FirstNumeric.position - 1, '')
FROM @T AS T
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT position = PATINDEX('%[0123456789]%', T.[Terminal Kodu])
) AS FirstNumeric;
```

Output:

| Name | Code |
| --- | --- |
| e-manat | 1135592398 |